# Opening an archived "Application Event Log" (Hidden Directory)

Tags: filesystems, log-files, windows-event-log, eventviewer

I'm an admin on the box.  I've turned off all the folder options "Hide protected operating system files" and turned on "Show hidden files and folders".

I can see this folder in Windows Explorer: 
C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs

but I cannot see it from Event Log Viewer MMC snap-in BizTalk Admin Console. 
In that tool, and others such as GamutLog-Viewer, when I do "file Open", and paste in the same directory, I get: \
C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs - Path does not exist - Check the path and try again.

From Windows Notepad, I can do "File Open", paste same, and I get the directory.

Why is it different from one tool to the other?

Should I just create a C:\EventLogArchive and archive all my logs there?

Here's a couple of screen shots from NotePad and NotePad++ showing how NotePad can navigate to the directory, and NotePad++ cannot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've added two screenshots to the original question.  What other details do you suggest I provide.  It's a physical machine (not-VM) running our production BizTalk environment.  Wouldn't this be either a security permissions issue, a UAC issue, or something like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `C:\Windows\Sysnative\winevt`

In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access `%windir%\System32`, the access is redirected to `%windir%\SysWOW64`.

32-bit applications can access the native system directory by substituting `%windir%\Sysnative` for `%windir%\System32`. `WOW64` recognizes `Sysnative` as a special alias used to indicate that the file system should not redirect the access. This mechanism is flexible and easy to use, therefore, it is the recommended mechanism to bypass file system redirection. Note that 64-bit applications cannot use the `Sysnative` alias as it is a virtual directory not a real one.

[From the File System Redirector technet article, here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 - A 32-bit program needs to use "SysNative" to access the "real" System32 directory.

Comment: Did you try it with IE or NotePad++?  I browsed to c:\windows then tried typing in sysnative, and get "file not found".  Same with c:\Windows\SysNative.  Maybe that works in code, but not from the browser dialogs windows?

Comment: Yes, from notepad++, looking at it as I write (there is no folder to click at though, you have to type/paste)

Comment: Okay, more interesting results.  If I type exactly as you provided, C:\Windows\Sysnative\winevt it works.  If I break it into chunks, and do C:\Windows, then try to type Sysnative, it does not work.  Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can re-produce this issue on my Windows 8.1 x64 as well with the latest version of Notepad++. As more careful people noticed that is because Notepad++ is x32 app and replacing 'system32' with 'sysnative' does the trick. if I type

```
C:\Windows\sysnative\winevt\logs\
```

I can see the files just fine.
[image]

Comment: I used NotePad and NotePad++ just as easy-to-reproduce examples.  We recently bought a tool called Event Log Explorer that also has the issue; it's my tool of choice.  Maybe these programs are using a different API to build the dialog/browser.  But it seems like if the directory is there, not protected, visible, etc... that it should be able to be seen by all tools in any "open dialog" window.

Comment: Yes...as long as they are using the exact same methods/APIs.

Comment: A file open in Sql 2008 SSMS cannot see it either, so even some Microsoft Tools are impacted.  Of course, I would never open an event log in SQL, but just an example of a Microsoft tool having the same issue. Likewise IE 8 cannot see the directory with File Open.

Comment: The problem is a 32-bit program accessing the real "System32" directory and the "redirection" that takes place "behind the scenes" in WOW64.

Comment: You are right, Evan!